# Android facebook cannot change event's profile picture

Tags: android, facebook, events

I use the old `facebook android api` for creating events. All work fine except when I am trying to post a `profile picture` for the event. The `facebook Graph api` says 
**You can add a profile picture to an event by issuing an HTTP POST request to /EVENT_ID/picture with the create_event permission for an admin of the event** with the following parameter:

```
source  multipart/form-data
```

Returns true if the request is successful.

so I used this code:

```
Bundle picture_parameters = new Bundle();
picture_parameters.putString("source", "https://foursquare.com/mapproxy/59.3280/18.0506/map.png");
response = Utility.mFacebook.request(eventId + "/picture", picture_parameters, "POST");
JSONObject myjson = Util.parseJson(response);
Log.v("INFO", "!!!picture posted "+ response);
```

indeed returns true but no picture !!

Answer (score 0):

The "source" needs to be the actual picture itself, not a url. That's why the content type is multipart/form-data, rather than a string.